# How Use Attribute Sets to Make a JTextPane with Text in Borders

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border

I know that you could use HTML to have a JTextPane with multiple lines of text where each line has a different border, but I am wondering how you would accomplish this using only attribute sets. I can't seem to find an attribute set that supports borders. Is there one, and if there is, how would I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to find an attribute set that supports borders. Is there one,

Not that I know of.

You might be able to use a `Highlighter`.

The [Rectangle Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) shows how you can paint a rectangle around pieces of text.

Comment: I think I should be able to override that to get what I want. Thanks!